# Image is not showing with uri source React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, express

I've checked several similar topics in Stackoverflow but I didn't find my answer.

I have this  component which is meant to show profile images in my app. I am serving images in my node server and it works just fine in the browser. It means when I open the link with the browser image is shown in my browser. it also works fine with my react web app.
in the react native app it is not shown, though.
I tested some other links from different sources and it works fine.
But the image links from my API end does not work in the react native.

```
  <Image source={{
        uri: 'https://mentalwill.xyz/API/ProfileImages/21190169ANDREW-NG.jpg' ,
      }} style={styles.profileImage} />
```

and the style:

```
  profileImage:{
  width: 200,
  height:200,
  borderRadius:100,
  marginTop:50
}
```

Comment: that's weird it's woking perfectly fine for me https://prnt.sc/vat3lw

Comment: So weird! thanks. at least now I know it's not a problem with my server at all.